# NSMutableAttributedString vertical alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a ellipse path for text. For fill path I used NSMutableAttributedString:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:15];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutParaStyle=[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

[mutParaStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[mutParaStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font
                                 ,NSFontAttributeName,mutParaStyle ,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil]; 

NSMutableAttributedString  *strText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attrsDictionary];
```

But this work only for horizontal text alignment. How i can apply vertical aligment?

I have this result:
[image]

But I need this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

But i have tried with vertical it is working fine for me, Below is the screenshot Let me know 
if i am wrong and also below is the code attached:--

[image]

```
NSString *allTheText = [tv string];
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutParaStyle=[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

[mutParaStyle setAlignment:kCTTextAlignmentRight];
[mutParaStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font
                                 ,NSFontAttributeName,mutParaStyle ,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil];

NSMutableAttributedString  *strText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:allTheText attributes:attrsDictionary];
[tv .textStorage appendAttributedString:strText];
```